# Controlling scroll viewer's scroll distance

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I'm placing 20 textblocks in scroll viewer, but it scrolling upto 7? I also want to control the scroll distance in get scrolled whenever my application starts?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you set `Height` of `ScrollViewer` to `Auto` and it don't fit to screen. Set it to `Parent` `Height`. I hope it will work than.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put up your code? Also make sure you have done these two things

1) Place it in a grid.row and set grid.rwo height to * 
2) Do not place the scrollviewer in a stackpanel